# (YoutubeAPI,Flutter) I don't see a popup to select a youtube chanel

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, youtube-api, google-authentication

I try to get users playlists after they sign-in with google method to my app.

When I try to fetch my youtube playlists from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list?apix=true and I put this as a request:

GET https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&maxResults=25&mine=true HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json

I see popup to select one of my many channels and everything is great. I have response type 200 and a full data

[image: Screenshot 2021-07-05 at 10 49 40]

BUT.......

When Im executing the same request from flutter app I don't see a popup and I have DetailedApiRequestError(status: 404, message: Channel not found.)

Can anyone help ?

Here is the code:

```dart
import 'package:extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth/extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth.dart'
    as auth;
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:googleapis/people/v1.dart';
import "package:googleapis/youtube/v3.dart";
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Google Sign In',
      home: SignInDemo(),
    ),
  );
}

class SignInDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => SignInDemoState();
}

class SignInDemoState extends State<SignInDemo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Google Sign In'),
        ),
        body: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
          child: _buildBody(),
        ));
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return ElevatedButton(
      child: const Text('SIGN IN'),
      onPressed: _handleSignIn,
    );
  }

  Future<void> _handleSignIn() async {
    final _googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn(
      scopes: [
        PeopleServiceApi.contactsReadonlyScope,
        YouTubeApi.youtubepartnerScope,
        YouTubeApi.youtubeForceSslScope,
        YouTubeApi.youtubeScope,
        YouTubeApi.youtubeReadonlyScope,
        YouTubeApi.youtubeChannelMembershipsCreatorScope,
        YouTubeApi.youtubeScope,
        YouTubeApi.youtubepartnerChannelAuditScope,
      ],
    );
    await _googleSignIn.signOut();
    await _googleSignIn.signIn();

    final httpClient = await _googleSignIn.authenticatedClient();
    final YouTubeApi youtubeApi = YouTubeApi((httpClient)!);

    final response = await youtubeApi.playlists.list(
      ["snippet"],
      mine: true,
      maxResults: 25,
    );
    print(response.items!.length);
  }
}
```

When I use ApiExplorer on https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list?apix=true I see popup with my channels lists and after selecting one of them I get a oauth token back which works. When I use this line "final httpClient = await _googleSignIn.authenticatedClient();" with practically All youtube scopes I also get oauth token but when I put it in my YoutubeApi request I get

```json
"error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Channel not found.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Channel not found.",
                "domain": "youtube.playlist",
                "reason": "channelNotFound",
                "location": "channelId",
                "locationType": "parameter"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I see the first popup. And I can choose my gmail account. But when I try to load some private data from youtube I should see second popup to choose the youtube channel because I have multiple channels assign to my google acount but the second popup don't open and I have error 404 channel not found and thats very strange because when I used https://developers.google.com/people which is very similar to youtube api everything is working great

Comment: It is a little more involved while trying to fetch from Google APIs from within Flutter. Thankfully, the official Flutter documentation has a great article on this particular case: [YouTube API - Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/google-apis)

Answer (score 0):

The issue here seems to be you didn't fully follow the documentation for this implementation.

Here on those rows is where the issue is:

```
final httpClient = await _googleSignIn.authenticatedClient();
final YouTubeApi youtubeApi = YouTubeApi((httpClient)!);
```

So what the [recommended implementation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/google-apis#4-obtain-an-authenticated-http-client) shows:

`var httpClient = (await _googleSignIn.authenticatedClient())!;`

Which basically creates a postfix `!` operator, which ensures casting, so in case the result of the `await _googleSignIn.authenticatedClient()` is null, what will be the case, since the user is not authenticated on first run, it casts its type to a `httpClient`.

But on your implementation, you've declared the `httpClient` as:

`final httpClient = await _googleSignIn.authenticatedClient();`

For this reason, when the code is first run, it'll return a failed state / null, because the user is not logged in, so your `YouTubeApi` won't be receiving the update on the user successful login, and thus you won't be able to access its token.

So changing this small detail should suffice for you :)

Comment: Nope still nothing plus a big red error after your changes: 
```dart
Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'AuthClient' which excludes null.
 - 'AuthClient' is from 'package:googleapis_auth/src/auth_client.dart' ('../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/googleapis_auth-1.1.0/lib/src/auth_client.dart').
        final YouTubeApi youtubeApi = YouTubeApi((httpClient)!);
```